# Using ObservableCollection to update icon location on map overlay (iOS, Xamarin Forms Maps)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, maps, observablecollection

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Maps to create a list of pins, with only the current location indicated by a different icon

I want to update the icon's location every 10 seconds with a GPS call, and so far I've only managed to draw a new icon each movement

I assumed having an ObservableCollection with a BindingProperty would take care of the movement but it doesn't?

My CustomMap class looks like this

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; }

public static readonly BindableProperty CustomPinsCoordinatesProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RouteCoordinates), typeof(ObservableCollection<CustomPin>), typeof(CustomMap), new ObservableCollection<CustomPin>(), BindingMode.TwoWay);

public ObservableCollection<CustomPin> CustomPinsCoordinates { 
get { return (ObservableCollection<CustomPin>)GetValue(CustomPinsCoordinatesProperty); }
set { SetValue(CustomPinsCoordinatesProperty, value); }}
```

I add the current location marker to the map, or update it, in my MainMap method

```
dPin = new CustomPin
{
Type = PinType.Place,
Position = new Position(newLoc.Latitude, newLoc.Longitude),
                    Label = "Current Position",
                    Id = "Current Position"
                };

var item = cPins.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Label == "Current Position");
if (item != null)
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: found a match in CustomPinsCoordinates, updating location ");
item.Position = newLoc;
}
else
{
TrackAdvertiser.CustomPinsCoordinates.Add(dPin);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Debug: added CustomPin to CustomPInsCoo " + dPin.Position.Latitude + "" + dPin.Position.Longitude);
cPins.Add((CustomPin)dPin);
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49355603/2249175 - obviously (although MSDN states otherwise), the collection does not fire when the children are changed.

Comment: What is your problem, you should specify it with more details perhaps with some screenshots?

Comment: Problem as I said in the description is the icon is being added to the overlay for every single point the GPS updates to, not just the last one, so I get a snail trail of imagery